# Keydown event while dragstart event

Tags: javascript, events

I have a drag function, that drags a game block in to a board game. While dragging the game block should rotate after a keydown event. But when I drag a block and press a key, the dragstart event will be canceled.

```
function dragndrop () {
    const draggables = document.querySelectorAll(".block")
    const squares = document.querySelectorAll(".square")
    const blocks_array = createListOfBlocksGrid()
    console.log(blocks_array)

    draggables.forEach(draggable => {
        draggable.addEventListener("dragstart", () =>{
            draggable.classList.add("dragging")
        })

        draggable.addEventListener("keydown", (ev) => {
            console.log("keydown")
        })

        draggable.addEventListener("dragend", () => {
            console.log("abgebrochen")
            draggable.classList.remove("dragging")
        })
    })

    
    
    squares.forEach(square => {
        
        square.addEventListener("dragenter", e => {
            e.preventDefault()
            const draggable = document.querySelector(".dragging")
            const draggingBlockId = Number(draggable.id)
            let yx_array = square.id.split(",")
            let y = Number(yx_array[0])
            let x = Number(yx_array[1])


            let currentBlock = blocks_array[Number(draggingBlockId)]

            for (i in currentBlock) {

                for (j in currentBlock[i]) {

                    if (currentBlock[i][j] == true) {
                        let yi = y+Number(i)
                        let xj = x+Number(j)

                        let trueSquare = document.getElementById(`${yi.toString()},${xj.toString()}`)
                        trueSquare.classList.add("dragenter")
                    } 
                }
            }
            
        })
```

I've tried to insert the keydown event in to the dragstart event.